# How to load the android webview in the background and show it after it finished

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask, splash-screen

Please tell me how to load the webview in the background.
I made an app that uses the android webview.
The problem is, to load the webview it is taking too much of the time..
so i dont want to show my website loading .. instead i need to show the splash screen and after webview is finished loading ,i want to show my completely loaded webview...
I tried  onPageStarted(to show the splash) and onPageFinished(to hide the splash) its not working ....
I tried AsyncTast doItBackground method but it is giving me the error that it has be called from the ui thead..
Please help me with the any source code or the example program to do this....

Answer (score 0):

Use below code- I have shown progressDialog, U can manage it as per your requirement

```
   web = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.web);

            WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

            progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), getString(R.string.app_name), "Loading...");

            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });

            web.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/Schapp-Demo-451986454993905/");
```